# Filter intermediary ManyToMany django

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Ingredient(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)



class Product(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=55)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )


class ProductIngredient(Model):
    product = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='product_ingredients')
    ingredient = ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    optional = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('product', 'ingredient'),)
        ordering = ('product__name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product} - {self.ingredient}'
```

I want to make two queries:

- select all products, whose ingredients contain strawberry AND milk
- select all products, whose ingredients contain strawberry OR milk

The first query is: `Product.objects.prefetch_related('product_ingredients__ingredient').filter(product__ingredients__ingredient__name='strawberry').filter(product__ingredients__ingredient__name='milk')`

Do I need to write `distinct` in the first query?
How to write the second query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to write distinct in the first query?

**No**, or at least not if the `product`-`ingredient` combination is unique, like here. It will be distinct, since the two ingredients are clearly distinct. You furthermore should not use `.prefetch_related(..)` here, unless you really want to render the `Product` with the related `Ingredient`s. So it is sufficient to write:

```
Product.objects.filter(
    product__ingredients__ingredient__name='strawberry'
).filter(
    product__ingredients__ingredient__name='milk'
)
```

> How to write the second query?

You can filter with an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
Product.objects.filter(
    product__ingredients__ingredient__name__in=['strawberry', 'milk']
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for complex lookups

```
Product.objects.prefetch_related('product_ingredients__ingredient').filter(Q(product__ingredients__ingredient__name='strawberry')|Q(product__ingredients__ingredient__name='milk'))
```