# Filter intermediary ManytoMany django with negation

Tags: django, django-models

This question is related to: [Filter intermediary ManytoMany django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225398/filter-intermediary-manytomany-django)

```
class Ingredient(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=55, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)



class Product(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=55)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )


class ProductIngredient(Model):
    product = ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='product_ingredients')
    ingredient = ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    optional = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('product', 'ingredient'),)
        ordering = ('product__name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.product} - {self.ingredient}'
```

I want to make two queries:

- select all products, whose ingredients don't contain strawberry AND milk
- select all products, whose ingredients don't contain strawberry OR milk

In this case I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your linked question you could use Q objects with an `.exclude()` instead of a `.filter()`. You can also negate Q objects by prefixing with a tilde (~):

Products with ingredients not containing strawberry AND milk

```
.filter(
    ~Q(product__ingredients__ingredient__name='strawberry') &
    ~Q(product__ingredients__ingredient__name='milk')
)
```

Products with ingredients not containing strawberry OR milk

```
.filter(~Q(product__ingredients__ingredient__name__in=['strawberry', 'milk']))
```